# how to enlarge the image in lwuit button using key presses events in lwuit

Tags: events, lwuit, keyrelease

Using LCDUI I have worked with key events it was successful. But I developed my whole application in lwuit I don't want to switch from lwuit to lcdui. Any body help me while pressing buttons I want to zoom In and Zoom out the image. Is there any key pressed for button events in LWUIT.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method

```
public void keyPressed(int keyCode) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
Form.addKeyListener() and addGameKeyListener()
```

You can also derive the form (or the focused component) and override keyPressed/Released as Tan suggested.